# Why this C++ code using OpenMP library throws an error of bad condition in for loop while compilation?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I tried to parallelize Sieve of Eratosthenes algoritm using OpenMP library.

My code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (uint p = 2; (p * p) <= n; ++p)
{
    if (prime[p] == true)
    {
        for (uint i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
            prime[i] = false;
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get error message:
`condition of OpenMP for loop must be a relational comparison ('<', '<=', '>', or '>=') of loop variable 'p'`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think you will have to use `sqrt`.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP has [restrictions](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu40.html#x63-1260002.9.1) on the condition in a `for` loop. The condition must be of the form `p relop var` or `var relop p`. Expressions using `p` are not allowed. (There are also restrictions on what `var` can be.)

In your case, you'll need to utilize the square root (`p <= sqrt(n)`) in your condition. However, this `sqrt` call needs to be made ahead of time and saved in another local variable (declared before the `#pragma omp` directive).

```
uint sqrtn = uint(sqrt(n));
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for (uint p = 2; p <= sqrtn; ++p)
```

With these restrictions on the condition, the OpenMP system can calculate how many times the loop will execute before entering it. This allows the work to be distributed appropriately.